# How to fill or Paint bucket in Inkscape without white space between two paths?

Tags: inkscape, fill, image-trace

In inkscape I imported a jpg map file and by using trace bitmap utility I created a set of paths. Now I am trying to fill the regions between maps using paint bucket tool( More specifically the boundaries of area are traced as black. And they are paths not single object with black color filled in it and with no strokes.). But it is not filling completely. I tried variying the threshold and others.

[image: Part of a Map traced from a JPG file. Black area is a path with black color fill]

But no luck. How to fill the space between boundaries without leaving white space.

Or

How to trace a map boundary as an object not as a path with black color fill in it.

Or

How to fill area between black color without using this paint bucket tool.

---

Answers of [Is it possible to get Inkscape's bucket fill to entirely fill regions marked by lines?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45008/is-it-possible-to-get-inkscapes-bucket-fill-to-entirely-fill-regions-marked-by) question partialy addresses the problem. Even though the question is somewhat same but answer is not clear.

Comment: Does this help: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45008/is-it-possible-to-get-inkscapes-bucket-fill-to-entirely-fill-regions-marked-by ?

Comment: @Takkat - that is a workaround soluton. In some cases the sharp bends on small areas this will not work for this same color stroke and its size (Some time it will spill over to other area also). Also it is not fool proof. If we fill on a large complex map it is very difficult to check whether all the white gaps are filled or not. And Searching for a fool proof solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select all the Paths with  :tool_selector:
2. Duplicate them (Ctrl+D)
3. Convert them to paths (Ctrl+Alt+C)
4. Create a union from the paths
   (Ctrl+Shift+ + )
5. Break Apart the new shape (Ctrl+Shift+k)

One of the two shapes created will be the exact fill. Delete the other.
The problem isn't that much complicated. But we want to find which is the exact fill from a total set of objects placed over and below.

Then change the fill color of the object will exactly solve this problem.

Thanks [slow dog](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1090&sid=99637de7e9087caf9899f891ecdfbbe9) in the inkscape forum for this quick solution.